# https htaccess exclude only one folder from redirecting to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I activated https on my site and I added to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

It's all ok, but I want to add an exception to a single folder only to not be redirected to https.
The folder is "public_html/files"

Comment: Where are my comments?

Comment: Why my comments are dissapear?